# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined Next.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, next.js

I'm using next js and using jquery, Bootstrap and few other js libraries.

This is my _app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from '../components';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import Script from "next/script";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return (
    <>
      <Script src="/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></Script>
      <Script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></Script>
      <Script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jstree.min.js" ></Script>
      <Script type="text/javascript" src="/js/template.js" ></Script>
      <Script src="/js/common.js" type="text/javascript" ></Script>
      <Script src="/js/global.js" type="text/javascript" ></Script>
      <Script src="/js/owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></Script>
      <Layout>
        <Toaster />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

But I'm getting this error,

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
>
> Call Stack  /js/bootstrap.min.js (6:37)

But the funny thing is in inspect element in the browser the files are loaded.
[image]

IS there any fix for this issue :(

Comment: I think its a path issue and should be `./js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js` with a dot?

Comment: Thanks a lot but in inspect element can access the file.

Comment: Try switching jQuery to "beforeInteractive" mode (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#beforeinteractive) so it loads earlier. Right now, Next is async loading all the scripts and it's possible that bootstrap is loading and initializing before jQuery is done loading.

Comment: When I switch to beforeInteractive mode I'm getting hydration errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.Js Script compenent loading strategy by default is after interactive but in your case jQuery need to load it first before interactive so your code will be somthing like this

```
<Script src="assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"></Script>
```

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/script